# How to get access to a reports xml content before rendering it using the report execution service

Tags: reporting-services

I use the following code to problematically render a report:

```
rsExecService.ReportExecutionService rsExec = this.CreateReportExecutionService();
rsExecService.ExecutionInfo ei = rsExec.LoadReport(path, historyID);

Byte[] results;
string mimeType = String.Empty;
rsExecService.Warning[] warnings = null;
string[] streamIDs = null;

results = rsExec.Render(format, deviceInfo, out extension, out encoding, out mimeType, out warnings, out streamIDs);
```

(Some variable definitions are missing because they're passed as parameters to the method).

The problem is that I need to do some preprocessing of the report, regarding localization, before rendering it.
I've looked at the ExecutionInfo ,'ei', and there doesn't appear to be a member that gives me access to the raw xml report content.

Is there another way to render a report that would allow me to change the xml first?

**ETA:** See answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've worked it out:

- First use the ReportingService2010 to download the report using
  GetItemDefinition(path).
- Perform whatever preprocessing you desire on
  the raw data.
- Instead of using ReportExecutionService.LoadReport(), use LoadReportDefinition()